# Best practices to build a hybrid Java application for both mobile and Web

Tags: java, spring, react-native, spring-mvc, controller

We need to build a hybrid Java application for both mobile and Web. We plan to use Spring MVC and React Native.

Could you please advise us the best practices so that we can re-use the code as much as possible for both mobile and Web and it should be easy to maintain.

Should we build a common service layer and two different controllers for Web and mobile  (using @Controller and @RestController). After that, these two controllers can call the same service.

For example, to display the information of all users of our application, we can have a common service UserInfoService, then we create two different controllers WebUseInforController (with path like /web/users/info) and MobileUserInfoController (with path like /mobile/users/info). These two controllers call the same UserInfoService. Is this a good idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your client requirement but I can suggest you some ways that may be helpful for you:

I worked on an enterprise financial application, on that application we follow the approach that we created a single server side (in your context single controller). That server side was used by by web application as well as android application. You can create services oriented or micro services application and expose your different services that will be reused in both android as well as web application.

```
**Web Application  -----------> |Server side| <--------- Android Mobile Application**
```

**Best Practise is that you should have a single server side and expose your services**

And nevertheless there is another less economical and fast option as well:

You can go for web progressive applications. Progressive web apps are websites that look and feel like an app. This means users can access all information and capabilities without downloading a mobile app. Some big giants converted there applications into WPA e.g Ali Express, FlipKart, Twitter Lite, BookMyShow, Forbes and many more.

In the web progressive application you can follow any WEB architecture you want. You can even create an android application by using that website link in android. or that Application will work perfect in mobile browser as well.